# How to run minimad.c in libmad(what is command and params)?

Tags: c, command, clib

Could please some explain how to run minimad.c in libmad(http://www.underbit.com/products/mad/)? I followed instructions in INSTALL file. But I am not good in C and I don't know what parameters need to be passed in main function. I don't understand what parameters in argv is using there(in main()).

Answer (score 0):

minimad.c is a simple demo program for the libmad library. If you build libmad according to the instructions, then you should be able to build the minimad binary just by running "make minimad" at the prompt. The parameters argv, etc., are passed from the command line when you run invoke the program -- this point is pretty well described in most textbooks on C programming.

If what you're really asking is how to use libmad in a program of your own, then that's a different matter. You can use the minimad.c source code as a guide to doing this, but it's non-trivial.